# Populating select options using jquery fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I was trying to populate select options from a JSON using jquery. Here is my html form code (with search options) -

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Country</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="country" placeholder="" data-live-search="true">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the code i have write to populate the form with documents and also catch and echo the selection -

```js
(function() {
  var url = "dummy.json";
    countries = [];
    divisions = [];
    districts = [];
    subdistricts = [];
  $.getJSON(url)
    .done(function( data ) {
      countries.push(data['Country']);
      divisions.push(data['Divisions']);
      districts.push(data['Districts']);
      subdistricts.push(data['Subdistricts']);
       $('#country').empty();
        for(i=0; i<countries[0].length; i++){
            $('#country').append('<option data-tokens="' + countries[0][i]["name"] +'" value="' + i + '">' + countries[0][i]["name"] + '</option>');
        };
        $('#country').change(function(){
                var selected = $( this ).val();
                console.log(selected);
            });
      });
})();
```

My problem is- the selection form is not populating after running the code. Is there any syntax error in my code ? Or am i approaching it in wrong way ? If anyone want to see the json file, i will post it here.

Here is my JSON file -

```
    {
    "Country": [
    {
      "id": "01",
      "name": "China",
      "capital": "Beijing",
      "divisions": "[01, 02, 03]",
      "districts": "[01, 02, 03]"
    },
    {
      "id": "02",
      "name": "Bangladesh",
      "capital": "Dhaka",
      "divisions": "[04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11]",
      "Districts": "[04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]"
    },
    {
      "id": "03",
      "name": "Singapore",
      "Capital": "Singapore City",
      "Divisions": "[12,13,14,15,16]",
      "Districts": "[32,33,34,35,36]"
    }
  ],
  "Divisions": [
    {
      "id": "01",
      "name": "Shengdong",
      "districts": [
        [
          "[01]"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "02",
      "name": "Anhui",
      "districts": [
        [
          "[02]"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "03",
      "name": "Fujian",
      "districts": [
        [
          "[03]"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "04",
      "name": "Barisal",
      "districts": "[4,5,6]"
    },
    {
      "id": "05",
      "name": "Chittagong",
      "Districts": "[07,08,09,10]"
    },
    {
      "id": "06",
      "name": "Dhaka",
      "Districts": "[11,12]"
    },
    {
      "id": "07",
      "name": "Khulna",
      "Districts": "[13,14]"
    },
    {
      "id": "08",
      "name": "Central Region",
      "Districts": [
        [
          "[15]"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "09",
      "name": "North Region",
      "Districts": [
        [
          "[16]"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "name": "East Region",
      "Districts": [
        [
          "[17]"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "11",
      "name": "North-east Region",
      "Districts": [
        [
          "[18]"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "name": "West Region",
      "Districts": [
        [
          "[19]"
        ]
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Districts": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Dongcheng",
      "Subdistricts": [
        [
          "[1]"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Yaohai",
      "Subdistricts": [
        [
          "[2]"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Luyang",
      "Subdistricts": [
        [
          "[3]"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Barisal",
      "Subdistricts": [
        [
          "[4]"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "Barguna",
      "Subdistricts": [
        [
          "[5]"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "name": "Bhola",
      "Subdistricts": "[6,7]"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "name": "Chittagong",
      "Subdistricts": "[8,9,10,11]"
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "name": "Cox's Bazar",
      "Subdistricts": [
        [
          "[12]"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "name": "Comilla",
      "Subdistricts": [
        [
          "[13]"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "name": "Feni",
      "Subdistricts": [
        [
          "[14]"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "11",
      "name": "Dhaka",
      "Subdistricts": [
        [
          "[15]"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "name": "Narayanganj",
      "Subdistricts": [
        [
          "[16]"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "13",
      "name": "Khulna",
      "Subdistricts": [
        [
          "[17]"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "14",
      "name": "Bagerhat",
      "Subdistricts": [
        [
          "[18]"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "15",
      "name": "Radin Mas SMC",
      "Subdistricts": [
        [
          "[19]"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "16",
      "name": "Jalan Besar GRC",
      "Subdistricts": [
        [
          "[20]"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "17",
      "name": "Mount Batten GRC",
      "Subdistricts": [
        [
          "[21]"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "18",
      "name": "Marine Parade GRC",
      "Subdistricts": [
        [
          "[22]"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "19",
      "name": "West Coast GRC",
      "Subdistricts": [
        [
          "[23]"
        ]
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Subdistricts": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Dailang",
      "postcodes": "[736200,404000,100000]"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Changchung",
      "postcodes": "[864000,504100,905050]"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Chengdu",
      "postcodes": "[994000,909100,109050]"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Agailjhara",
      "postcodes": "[8240,8241,8242]"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "Amtali Upazella",
      "postcodes": "[9940,9941,8878]"
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "name": "Bhola Sadar",
      "postcodes": "[7230,7741,7752]"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "name": "Daulatkhan",
      "postcodes": "[8650,8871,8880]"
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "name": "Sitakund",
      "postcodes": "[4320,4321,4325]"
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "name": "Satkania",
      "postcodes": "[4460,4461,4458]"
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "name": "Port",
      "postcodes": "[4530,4555,4532]"
    },
    {
      "id": "11",
      "name": "Dabal Muring",
      "postcodes": "[4320,4321,4448]"
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "name": "Chokaria",
      "postcodes": "[5320,5321,5432]"
    },
    {
      "id": "13",
      "name": "Daudkandi",
      "postcodes": "[6432,6433,6555]"
    },
    {
      "id": "14",
      "name": "Feni sadar",
      "postcodes": "[3240,3241,3378]"
    },
    {
      "id": "15",
      "name": "Dhanmondi",
      "postcodes": "[2330,2441,2878]"
    },
    {
      "id": "16",
      "name": "Narayanganj Sadar",
      "postcodes": "[6444,6543,6657]"
    },
    {
      "id": "17",
      "name": "Batiaghat",
      "postcodes": "[7780,7781,7778]"
    },
    {
      "id": "18",
      "name": "Bagerhat Sadar",
      "postcodes": "[7450,7451,7458]"
    },
    {
      "id": "19",
      "name": "Changi",
      "postcodes": "[736200,404000,555776]"
    },
    {
      "id": "20",
      "name": "Quenstown",
      "postcodes": "[787899,878788,987789]"
    },
    {
      "id": "21",
      "name": "Clementi",
      "postcodes": "[989778,976543,975432]"
    },
    {
      "id": "22",
      "name": "Tuas",
      "postcodes": "[109901,110900,121345]"
    },
    {
      "id": "23",
      "name": "East Region",
      "postcodes": "[609098,567654,765432]"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Latest EDIT:**

I have checked in the console. HTML form with options value is loading perfectly, but for some reason my form is not showing options. Here is my latest code -

```
for(var i=0; i<countries[0].length; i++){
        $('#country').append('<option data-tokens="' + countries[0][i]["name"].toLowerCase() +'" value="' + countries[0][i]["id"] + '">' + countries[0][i]["name"] + '</option>');
    };
```

HTML code after loading in the console -

```
<select id="country" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" placeholder="" tabindex="-98">
    <option value="01" data-tokens="china">China</option>
    <option value="02" data-tokens="bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
    <option value="03" data-tokens="singapore">Singapore</option>
</select>
```

Any reason for such phenomenon ?

Comment: change it to `$('#country').append('<option data-tokens="' + countries[0][i][name] +'" value="' + i + '">' + countries[0][i][name] + '</option>');`

Comment: Any error in the Console?

Comment: @CarlosDelgado No error in the console.

Comment: Can you please show the structure of the "data" received of the json using json stringify?

Comment: @TamilSelvan It haven't worked.

Comment: @CarlosDelgado I have added the whole JSON with question.

Comment: [name] is undefined. I do not see where in the code you defined name? Did you mean to use ['name']?

Comment: @MohyEldeen I have used ["name"] instead of [name], result is still the same.

Comment: can you post your new code after changing it to ['name']? just this line :)

Comment: @MohyEldeen ... Done :)

Comment: Your example is really running for me. I do not see a problem. I suspect the way you are referencing your js file of where you are placing your script. Also, make sure about the location of your jquery lib

Comment: here is the plnkr running with no problem: https://plnkr.co/edit/gist:1986619?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106781/discussion-between-ni8mr-and-mohy-eldeen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems my problem was occurring for the **selectpicker** class i have used. The plugin i have used to generate the search options for the selection has its own criteria for populating options in a select form. Here is the link of their documentation - https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh

Here is my revised **JS** code -

```
(function() {
  var url = "dummy.json",
    countries = [],
    divisions = [],
    districts = [],
    subdistricts = [],
  $.getJSON(url)
    .done(function( data ) {
        countries.push(data['Country']);
        divisions.push(data['Divisions']);
        districts.push(data['Districts']);
        subdistricts.push(data['Subdistricts']);

        var option_string = '';

        for(var i=0; i<countries[0].length; i++){
            option_string += '<option data-tokens="' + countries[0][i]["name"].toLowerCase() +'" value="' + countries[0][i]["id"] + '">' + countries[0][i]["name"] + '</option>';
        }

        $('#country').empty().append(option_string).change(function(){
            var selected = $(this).val();
            console.log(selected);
        }).selectpicker('refresh');

      });
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the loop for :

```
for(var i=0; i<countries[0].length; i++){
    $('#country').append('<option data-tokens=' + countries[0][i].name +'value=' + i + '>' + countries[0][i].name + '</option>'); 
};
```

Comment: There is no syntax difference between **countries[0][i].name** and **countries[0][i]["name"]**.

Comment: I have added it later and having the same problem.

Comment: That's really weird , adding var to the counter maybe ?

Comment: sorry for late response. I have added a **var** to the counter. But now i am having a new problem. The code snippet - **$('#country').append('<option data-tokens="' + countries[0][i]["name"] +'" value="' + i + '">' + countries[0][i]["name"] + '</option>');** is pointing out to a ReferenceError- **i is not defined**.  :(   Though, **console.log(i)** is printing fine.